# Searching Arraylists with instanceof for a user query JAVA

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, instanceof

The searchDatabase method will accept a query string and search the ArrayList to see if the object contains the query(your search should be case-insensitive!) as the name or is of that object type (Hint: use instanceof to check for object type). It will return an ArrayList containing all of the values whose objects contain the query string.

I need to see if the query is the same as a class name (Such as Don/Talent/Overseer) and if it is then I print all objects of that type. If it's equal to a name in one of the objects then I just print that object out. I am confused as to what to do from here. I am looping through all goons in the Database and checking if they are instances of Don/Overseer/Talents and if they are then checking if the user query is equal to the object type and if it is print all of those objects but if it isn't then checking if it's equal to the name of any objects of type "Dom" in the arraylist.

```
protected ArrayList<Goon> searchDatabase(String query)
{
    ArrayList<Goon> clone = new ArrayList<Goon>();
    for(Goon a : goonDB)
    {
        if(a instanceof Don)
        {
            if(query.equalsIgnoreCase("don"))
            {

            }
            else 
            {
                if(a.getName().equals(query))
                {

                }
            }
        }
        else if(a instanceof Overseer)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement is ambiguous, here are my assumptions:

- Goon is a parent class of Don/Talent/Overseer (They extend/implement
  it).
- You accept a query which stands for either object or a name
  property in one of the implementation classes.
- If query is a type name: return all objects of that type in a list.
- Otherwise, check if it matches a name property: return all objects that have the same name property. (Although you said print that one object, I am going to ignore that, because then I would be returning null and more requirement questions arise)

I don't want to write it the code for you, because this looks like a homework assignment and you are much better off struggling a bit, but here is a logic that you would need to use to follow above assumptions:

I would first check if query is Don/Talent/Overseer. If it is then go through the list and add all objects that are of that type (instanceof) to your clone list . If it isn't, then go through the whole list and add those that have the name matching the query. Return the list.

Comment: That's exactly it. I'm just not sure how to add the ones that are instanceof to the clone list. I know how to add to an arraylist but specifically adding ALL of that type to an arraylist is confusing to me?

Comment: Just kidding, I figured it all out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although I see you've already figured it out. I still want to post my answer :P (or else I made it for nothing). Maybe others who have the same problem can use it. I asumed that Don and Overseer implemented Goon by the way. And as a solution I just looped over the database checking if the query and the class name matched.

I also added a little main method to test the search code. And as you can see in the output only the `Don's` are printed.

```
package stackoverflow.question_26510341;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Search {

static ArrayList<Goon> goonDB = new ArrayList<Goon>();

public static void main(String[] args){
    goonDB.add(new Don());
    goonDB.add(new Don());
    goonDB.add(new Overseer());
    ArrayList<Goon> list = searchDatabase("Don");
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}

protected static ArrayList<Goon> searchDatabase(String query){
    ArrayList<Goon> clone = new ArrayList<Goon>();
    Iterator<Goon> iterator = goonDB.iterator();
    Goon temp;
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        if(query.equals("Don") && (temp = iterator.next()) instanceof Don){
            clone.add(temp);
        }else if(query.equals("Overseer") && (temp = iterator.next()) instanceof Overseer){
            clone.add(temp);
        }//etc...
    }
    return clone;
}

private static interface Goon{
}

private static class Overseer implements Goon{
}

private static class Don implements Goon{
}
```

}